# Auto generated code in the init file when updating packages

Tags: init-file, customize

Every time I use the package manager it puts auto generated code in the init.el file:

```el
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 ...
 )

(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(fringe ((t (:background "grey10"))))
 ...
 )
```

This doesn't seem to be doing anything critical and only messes up my interface and theme colors.

Is there a way to stop Custom generated code?

Or at least this specific code (I'm assuming it's coming from the packages I have installed).

Comment: It shouldn't mess up your interface or theme colors. When you install/delete packages, `package-selected-packages` gets updated everytime. This is the default behavior. You can have two options:- make emacs stop generating custom info (not recommended) or have emacs put the custom generated messages into a separate file so that it's not cluttering your `init.el`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I just put the custom generated code into a separate custom file which is great. The main issue is that I have my fringe color set to `background: background` and every time I use the package manager it adds `'(fringe ((t (:background "grey10"))))` to the `custom-set-faces` which makes my fringes black instead of white. And I have no idea how to stop it.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you put the custom generated code in a separate file, you have to load it manually using `(load custom-file :no-error :no-message)`.  Also, there must be something in your `init.el` file generating the fringe face in `custom-set-faces`.

Comment: If you have any `custom-set-faces` in your `init.el`, replace it with `(set-face-attribute 'face-name nil <face settings go here>)`. That should solve the fringe problem

Comment: Thanks, I haven't found the culprit yet. But since I organized my init file a bit better It seems to have stopped generating `custom-set-faces`.

Comment: The comments here apply to a different, unposed question, which apparently has to do with "messes up my interface and theme colors". Please pose a separate question for that - *specifying* just what you mean by "messes up...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set option **`custom-file`** (to a different file from your init file).

Then Customize will use your `custom-file` instead of your init file.

This is good practice. It keeps your manually edited code apart from Customize's automatically managed code.

One minor caveat: Even though `custom-file` is a user option, *set it in your init file* instead of using Customize to manage it.

After you set `custom-file` in your init file, explicitly *load it* from your init file: `(load-file custom-file)`.

Comment: You didn't mention my favorite thing about setting `custom-file`: if you don't like the automatically generated file, you don't have to load it at all! I call mine `garbage.el`. :)

Comment: @Omar: Why would you customize something if you don't *ever* want to use those customizations? I can understand perhaps *conditionally* loading them, but *never*?

Comment: That's not my situation, @Drew. I *do* want to use customizations and *always* load mine, I just don't like the automatically generated custom file for two reasons: 1) my hand written `custom-set-faces` has some conditional stuff (I use the Consolas font on Windows, but not on Linux) and I couldn't easily figure out how to get Emacs to generate that automatically, 2) Emacs's idea of tidy is "put everything together in alphabetical order", my idea of tidy is "separate settings by the package they apply to" --so I put `custom-set-variables` calls in my `use-package` `:config` sections.